# Child page not appearing in the main menu

Tags: control-panel

On our website www.efcgroup.net we have created new new product under a ghost page (under parent). We can see the new page heading in side bar but not under main menu at home screen.

In this example, the page is BOP hoists under Subsea Handling Equipment under mechanical handling. Please help

Comment: Can you share the template code you're using to generate the main menu?  As well as a screenshot of (what I assume) is the structured section you're using to create the navigation?